# Using x2 image for Retina displayes CSS

Tags: html, css, retina-display

I am using this query to identify retina display:

```
 for none retina displayes
 .logo {
       background-position: -242px -138px;
       width: 67px;
       height: 14px;
 }

 @media
 only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
 only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),
 only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
     .logo, arrow, ... {
       background: url(../img/sprites_2x.png) no-repeat;
     }

      .logo {
         background-position: -336px -20px;
         width: 134px;
         height: 28px;
      }
 }
```

Now this does not fix the problem, because images are not 2x the size. How to write my css so it uses the correct ratio and scale of images for retina displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using two different sprites. Not only that the images were 2x, but the order was different.

Use the sprite-sheets that has images on the same position and then this is the css.

```
 .left, .right, ... {
      background-image: url(../img/sprites.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
.left, .right, ... {
   background-image: url(../img/sprites_2x.png);
   background-size: size of the sprite.png;
}

.left {
   background-position: sprite.png position;
   width: sprite.png width;
   height: sprite.png height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the standard for naming retina image is by adding `@2x` on filename.

How about this,,

```
/* for non retina display */    
.logo {
   background: url(../img/sprites.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: -242px -138px;
   width: 67px;
   height: 14px;
}

/* for retina display, using media query and @2x flag */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .logo {
        background: url(../img/sprites@2x.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: -336px -20px;
    }
}
```

or maybe you can use [retina js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) to ease